# starting Jupyter in Docker with shell script

Tags: bash, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Its 2023 and I'm still manually typing in my hostname IP address and port into the browser to access jupyter notebook from within a docker container. You would think we know how to do this at this point?  To catch anyone up to date:

1. first run docker with `'docker run -ti - --ipc=host -p:8888:8888 -v $workspace:/workspace <container>`
2. from inside docker execute 'hostname -I' to get ip.
3. run jupyter '`jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --no-browser`'
4. then get your output which tells you to click or copy/paste:
   `'Or copy and paste this URL: http://hostname:8888/?token=c003e96fbd68fa10c4c3087ac014cd8e81229631095b3a'`
5. to which you have to copy/paste and substitute in your hostname ip for hostname to get to the notebook.

Obviously this is inelegant.   I tried the following solution and can't get it to work either.  Has anyone come up with a better way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the IP address
hostname -I
ip_address=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')

# Start Jupyter notebook with the IP address
jupyter notebook --ip="${ip_address}" --allow-root --no-browser
```